# How can i use an Enum in Struts2 if statement

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have two jsp files as follow:

```
myform.jsp
<%@ page contentType='text/html; charset=UTF-8' errorPage='' %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<s:form id="myform" name="myform" namespace="/" theme='simple' action='createPage' method='post'>
    <table  width='100%'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width='100%'> 
                    <s:select id='parameterDataType' name='parameterDataType' theme="xhtml" required="true" key='param.datatype' list='#application.myList' emptyOption="true" listKey='listKey' listValue='listValue'/>
                </table>
                <table width='100%'>
                    <s:if test="parameterDataType != null">
                        <tr id='defParameterDefaultValue'>
                            <td class="tdLabel" >
                                <s:label cssClass="label" key="param.value"/></td>
                            <td ><%@ include file='/pages/datatypes.jsp' %></td>
                        </tr> 
                    </s:if>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</s:form>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
    <s:url id="reloadPage" namespace="/" action="reloadPage" />

        function reloadPage()
        {
            var form = document.forms[0];
            form.action = '<s:property value="reloadPage"/>';
            form.action += '?parameterDefaultValue=';
            form.submit();
        }    

        $("#parameterDataType").change(function()
        {
            reloadPage();
        });
</script>
```

and

```
datatype.jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

<s:if test="parameterDataType == 'CODE' ">
    <s:textfield id='parameterDefaultValue' name='parameterDefaultValue' theme="simple" size='27'/>
</s:if>

<s:if test="parameterDataType == 'DATE' ">
    <sj:datepicker id='parameterDefaultValue' name='parameterDefaultValue' parentTheme="simple" displayFormat="%{session.sessionAttr.pref.dateDisplayformat}" appendText="%{session.sessionAttr.pref.dateAppendText}" changeMonth="%{session.sessionAttr.pref.changeMonth}" changeYear="%{session.sessionAttr.pref.changeYear}"/>
</s:if>
<s:if test="parameterDataType == 'BUSINESS_UNIT' ">
    <s:select id='parameterDefaultValue' name='parameterDefaultValue' theme="simple" list='#session.businessUnitSelectList' listKey='id' listValue='name' emptyOption='true' />
</s:if>
<s:if test="parameterDataType == 'TERM' ">
    <s:select id='parameterDefaultValue' name='parameterDefaultValue' theme="simple" list='#session.termList' listKey='id' listValue='description' emptyOption='true' />
</s:if>
```

and an action class method

```
public String reloadPage()
{
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

My aim is to display the a field in the datatype.jsp based on the value selected in myform.jsp.
When a user for example selects CODE from the myform.jsp select, the page reloads to include the datatype.jsp. If i use the property tag i.e.

```
 <s:property value="parameterDataType" />
```

to print the value of parameterDataType in the datatype.jsp, i get the value CODE but it never enters the if statement. 
Please is there anything that i am doing wrong? if there is a better way of achieving this, i will appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I later solved the issue using a similar technique i got on this site

```
<s:if test="parameterDataType == @com.myenum.Values@CODE">
    DO SOMETHING
</s:if>
```

thanks for your responses

Answer (score 0):

Try `<s:if test="#parameterDataType == 'CODE' ">` with the hashtag ('#').

The hashtag is used in OGNL to reference variables.  In some Struts2 tags (such as the property tag), it is unnecessary to use the hashtag because it is implicit that a variable is being referenced, i.e. the 'value' attribute of the property tag will *always* reference a variable, therefore it is unnecessary to use the hashtag to specify that the value is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

OGNL isn't very magical, If parameterDataType is a string then just use a string method like so:

```
<s:if test="parameterDataType.equalsIgnoreCase('CODE')">
    DO SOMETHING
</s:if>
```